# load certain content only on first page of pagination

Tags: pagination

So on my blog page I'm first loading the 2 most recent articles and display them at the top of the page, then I'm getting the rest of the post beneath.
This is the code:

```
 <?php 
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date", 'cat'=>'-8, -9, -7, -6, -5, -4', 'paged'=> $paged);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );

echo '<div class="latest_new_posts">';
    echo'<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"></div>';
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
 <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mobile-padding" >
     <div class="blog-date-news"><span><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span></div>
     <div class="blog-container">
     <div class="news-blog-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>
     <div class="news-blog-excerpt"> <?php echo excerpt(700); ?> </div>
     <div class="news-blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src="..."/></a></div>
</div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container white" style="padding:50px 0;">
    <div class="container-max">
       <?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : '1'; ?>

        <?php 
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5,  'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date",'cat'=>'-8, -9, -7, -6, -5, -4','paged'=> $paged);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
echo '<div class="latest_new_posts main-news">';
?>

 <?php 
     $wp_query = new WP_Query('$args'.$paged);
    ?>

    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
<?php foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="position:relative; margin:45px 0;" >
     <div class="blog-date-news main-news-date"><span><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span></div>
     <div class="blog-container main-news-container">
     <div class="news-blog-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>
     <div class="news-blog-excerpt"> <?php echo excerpt(500); ?> </div>
     <div class="news-blog-more main-news-blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src="..."/></a></div>
</div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

 <div class="blog-page-next"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next', $wp_query->max_num_pages );
             ?> </div>

     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

AS you can see I have enabled pagination. Now I only need the first two posts at the top to display on the first page of the pagination, not on any of the others.

I've tried it like this:

```
    <?php 
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date", 'cat'=>'-8, -9, -7, -6, -5, -4');
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
if( !is_paged() ) { 
echo '<div class="latest_new_posts">';
    echo'<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1"></div>';
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
 <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mobile-padding" >
     <div class="blog-date-news"><span><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span></div>
     <div class="blog-container">
     <div class="news-blog-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></div>
     <div class="news-blog-excerpt"> <?php echo excerpt(700); ?> </div>
     <div class="news-blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img src="...."/></a></div>
</div>
    </div>
    };
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But this doesn't work and breaks the site. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, it looks like this is nothing to do with your use of is_paged() (which looks correct) but that your closing if and endforeach statements are the wrong way round? You need to close the foreach() before you close the if().